# Display required fields

Tags: qt

Is there any class for highlighting required fields in Qt? For C# there's ErrorProvider. Does Qt has anything similar?

Answer (score 2):

> For C# there's ErrorProvider. Does Qt has anything similar?

Not that I'm aware of.

Probably the easiest way is to use [QWidget::setStylesheet()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) to set a background (or whatever) to highlight the required fields.

Adding an icon next to the required field -- a red asterisk, say -- would be fairly straightforward: create a Field class using a horizontal layout with a required-field icon widget, a label and a 'field' widget, and give it a setRequired(bool) function.

I guess you could also use [QStyle](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstyle.html) to create a custom widget.